# How to select the first 3 rows and then add the fourth one (if any) till n-1

Tags: r

I want to write a loop to deal with large data which has more than 200 data.frames each data.frame has different number of rows. in each data.frame I wanna select the first 3 rows then do my analyses. If the data has fourth row, I need to add it to the firth 3 rows then if the data has fifth row I need to add it to the four rows and so on till I get n-1 rows.

Ex, in the first data.frame I have n=6 rows, I wanna select the first 3 rows then do my analyses (like prediction and more analyses) then add the fourth row to the previous selected 3 rows then do my analyses.

```
year <- c("1977", "1988", "1990", "2000", "2010", "2015")
y <- c(-0.12, -0.32, -0.23, -0.13, -0.4, -0.1)
s <- c(0.012, 0.023, 0.067, 0.076, 0.088, 0.003)
data <- data.frame(year, y, s)
```

so I wanna deal with first 3 rows as

```
  year     y     s
1 1977 -0.12 0.012
2 1988 -0.32 0.023
3 1990 -0.23 0.067
```

Then add the fourth row to the previous selected 3 rows then do my analyses.

```
  year     y     s
1 1977 -0.12 0.012
2 1988 -0.32 0.023
3 1990 -0.23 0.067
4 2000 -0.13 0.076
```

Then add the fifth row to the previous selected 4 rows then do my analyses.

```
  year     y     s
1 1977 -0.12 0.012
2 1988 -0.32 0.023
3 1990 -0.23 0.067
4 2000 -0.13 0.076
5 2010 -0.40 0.088
```

Another data.frame had n=33 rows so I need to start with the first 3 rows then do my analysis then add the fourth row to my first 3 rows then do my analysis till I reach the row number n-1=32 which is before the last row (data.frame has n=33).

By for loop I can deal with each data.frame separately but for each data.frame I wanna a way how to select only the first 3 rows then do my analyses then add the new row till the row n-1

Comment: Not clear about the expected. May be, you need `lapply(3:(nrow(df1) -1), function(i) head(df1, i))`. if it is a `list` of data.frames, then `lapply(lst1, function(dat) lapply(3:(nrow(dat)-1), function(i) head(dat, i)))`

Comment: @akrun thank you, but I need to deal with each selected rows separately.

Comment: it is doing a loop selection if you check the `lapply` with `3:(nrow(df1) -1)`

Comment: sorry I didn't get it, how can I get the mean and the variance in each selected rows for example?

Comment: You meant for 'y' and 's' ?

Comment: Please check the solution below.  Not clear whether you wanted that or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using loops. The results show information about the data frame and the number of rows used for calculations:

```
# create sample data with name format data__x
for (i in 1:10){
  n=sample(5:50,1)
  assign(paste0("data__", i), data.frame(year=sample(1850:2020, n), 
                                         y=sample(seq(-0.5, 0, by=0.01), n),
                                         s=sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.001), n)))}
# get names by pattern 
data_names <- ls.str(pattern = "^data__\\d+")

# create empty results
results <- tibble(data=as.character(), n_rows=as.numeric(),  mean_y=as.numeric(), mean_s=as.numeric())

for (j in 1:length(data_names)) { # iterate over list of data.frames
  dt_name <- data_names[j]
  dt <- get(dt_name) # get value of variable by name
  
  for (i in 3:(nrow(dt)-1)) { # iterate over rows
    results[nrow(results) + 1, ] <- list(dt_name, i, mean(dt$y[1:i]), mean(dt$s[1:i])) # add row to results
  } 
}
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 225 x 4
   data    n_rows mean_y mean_s
   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 data__1      3 -0.257  0.652
 2 data__1      4 -0.252  0.544
 3 data__1      5 -0.246  0.512
 4 data__1      6 -0.22   0.492
 5 data__1      7 -0.259  0.503
 6 data__1      8 -0.272  0.476
 7 data__1      9 -0.271  0.497
 8 data__1     10 -0.256  0.492
 9 data__1     11 -0.265  0.486
10 data__1     12 -0.247  0.448
# … with 215 more rows
```